# How to join two high order functions?

Tags: haskell

I would like to solve an equation that is dynamically generated.  I found a good library
in HackageDB that can calculate the approximate roots using Newton-Raphson method.  However, the newton function takes a function (with type signature Num a => a -> a ) as an equation.
My question is, it possible to append functions together?  For example: (not proper syntax)

```
join :: (a->a) ->(a->a)->(a->a)
join func1 func2 = func1+func2


For instance:
if func1 = 1+2*X+5*X^2 , func2 = 5 + 4*x + 2*x^3
then func3 = join func1 func2  
func3 is `6 + 6*x +  5*x^2 + 2*x^3?
```

I'm thinking of two ways to do this.  Because each small function is dynamically generated I will have to simplify the function to the form above then store the information in a data type for example: (not proper syntax)

```
data FuncInfo = Info [Double]    
  if 1 + 2*x + 3*x^2   ---->  Info [1,2,3]
     5 + 4*x^3         ---->  Info [5,0,0,4]
```

This way adding the two data and creating the new function should be easy.  However, in reality it's not easy to do due to the fact the small functions that is dynamically generated is really
hard to simplify ( A small function may look like this:  `10 / (1+x)^5` ).

The other way I'm thinking is to just append the functions together so that there is no need to do simplification nor store into a new data type for example:

```
func1 = 10 / (1+x) ^5
func2 =  25 / (1+x) ^9
newfunc = (10 / (1+x) ^5) + (25 / (1+x) ^9)
```

Comment: I don't quite see what's "high(er?) order" about your example functions, and the way I read your question you want to add functions pointwise, not append them. So I might be misunderstanding you, but suggested a solution below still...

Comment: take a look to the haskell wiki [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Add_polynomials)

Comment: Since there is an accepted answer, I'm writing this as a comment: For this kind of "joining", the [`Applicative`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids) instance of `(->) r` is very helpful: `newfunc = (+) <$> func1 <*> func2`. Note that this works beautifully for all kinds of n-ary operators, not only addition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. The function values have to have a notion of addition, though, so we'll have to restrict to functions of type `(Num b) => a -> b`. Then you can simply do

```
functionSum :: (Num b) => (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
functionSum f g x = (f x) + (g x)
```

(I've avoided using the name `join`, as most people might then think of [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3ajoin) well-established function).

So, for example, if

```
func1 :: Double -> Double
func1 x = 1+2*x+5*x^2

func2 :: Double -> Double
func2 x = 5+4*x+2*x^3
```

then

```
*> :t (functionSum func1 func2)
(functionSum func1 func2) :: Double -> Double
```

---

You seem to indicate in parts of your question that you have polynomials stored as lists of coefficients. If `[a0, a1, a2, ...]` describes the polynomial a0 + a1*x + ..., then you can also use `zipWith (+) list1 list2` to produce a new list of coefficients representing the sum of the two polynomials. Take care handling cases of finite lists of differening lengths, thought (hint: add zeros to the shorter list to match the length of the longer).

Comment: By the way, does anybody know why `(Num b) => (a -> b)` isn't an instance of `Num` under pointwise operations anyway? Does it just come down (as so often) to `Num` being quirky?

Comment: Historically `instance (Num b) => Num(a -> b)` wasn't possible because `Num` was a subclass of `Eq`. Now it would be possible, but I wouldn't necessarily consider it a good idea – functions onto a `Num` field do form a [_vector space_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-space/0.8.6/doc/html/Data-VectorSpace.html) over the field (additive group by means of pointwise addition), but operations such as pointwise multiplication often don't really make sense conceptually, as it destroys the basis-invariance of the vector space. I therefore prefer to keep the two classes apart.

Comment: Good points. Thanks. I had forgotten about the whole Eq thing.

Comment: I guess it would be OK if Num and friends were split into more fine-grained and mathematically sensible typeclasses, where you'd say make `AdditiveMonoid b => (a -> b)` an instance of `AdditiveMonoid`, right?